# M2DOC : s it possible for my service to return specific object and manipulate it

Tags: m2doc

I developped my owned M2DOC service and I would like to manipulate it like I manipulate java object in my template.

I have an object "Application" with some attributes, and I would like, in my template, to do something like : App.getName() to print the attribute name of the object Application.

I read that my service must return type like Mtable, MImage...

But Is it possible for my service to return object like Application and manipulate it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but you will have to create a service for each getter like that:

```
public Application getMyApplication(...);

public String getName(Application app) {
  return app.getName();
}
```

To do this in a generic way you would probably have to implement a JavaMethodService that use the receiver (first argument of service call) as the instance of the invoke. Also you will need a way to register (IQueryEnvironment.registerService()) such services.